# How to pass a return value from one PostgreSQL query to another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries. The first creates a new user. The table has three fields, `id`, `name` and `email`. The `id` field is an autoincrement value.

The second query creates additional data related to this user, using the ID value.

How can I pass the `RETURNING` value of the first to the second query?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO users (
  name, 
  email
) VALUES (
  'John Doe',
  'johndoe@whatever.com'
) RETURNING id;

INSERT INTO users_stuff (
  user_id,
  money,
  hasCar
) VALUES (
  id,
  1000,
  false
);
```

The above example doesn't work because the second query never receives the first one's `RETURNING` value, which would be the new record's autoincrement ID.

Is there a way though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH u AS (
      INSERT INTO users (name, email)
          VALUES ('John Doe', 'johndoe@whatever.com')
          RETURNING id;
     )
INSERT INTO users_stuff (user_id, money, hasCar) 
    SELECT u.id, 1000, false
    FROM u;
```